# Node.js: non-blocking code

Tags: node.js, blocking, nonblocking

I'm just starting off with Node.js and struggling with some of the finer points of non-blocking (asynchronous?) code. I know there are lots of questions about blocking vs non-blocking code already, but after reading through some of them, I still couldn't sort out this issue.

As a learning exercise, I made a simple script that loads URLs from a file, queries them using the `request` module, and notifies me if a URL is the New York Times homepage.

Here is a MWE:

```
// CSV Parse test
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var text = fs.readFileSync('input.txt','utf8');
var r_isnyt = /New York Times/; 

var data = [];

parse(text, {skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){

    for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        console.log ('Logging from within parse function:');
        console.log ('URL: '+data[r][0]+'\n');

        var url = data[r][0];

        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log ('Logging from within request function:');
            console.log('Loading URL: '+url+'\n');
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                if (r_isnyt.exec(body)){ 
                    console.log('This is the NYT site! ');
                }
                console.log ('');
            }
        });         
    }
});
```

And here is my `input.txt`:

```
http://www.nytimes.com/
www.google.com
```

From what I understood of non-blocking code, this program's flow would be:

- `parse(text, {skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){` loads the data and returns the lines of the input file in a 2D array, which is complete and available right after that line.
- `For` Loop iterates through it, loading URLs with the line `request(url, function(error, response, body) {`, which is non-blocking (right?), so the For loop continues without waiting for the previous URL to finish loading.
- As a result, you could have multiple URLs being loaded at once, and the `console.log` calls within `request` will print in the order the responses are received, not the order of the input file.
- Within `request`, which has access to the results of the request to `url`, we print the URL, check whether it's the New York Times, and print the result of that check (all blocking steps I thought).

That's a long-winded way of getting around to my question. I just wanted to clarify that I thought I understood the basic concepts of non-blocking code. So what's baffling me is that my output is as follows:

```
>node parsecsv.js
Logging from within parse function:
URL: http://www.nytimes.com/

Logging from within parse function:
URL: www.google.com

Logging from within request function:
Loading URL: www.google.com

Logging from within request function:
Loading URL: www.google.com

This is the NYT site!

>
```

I understand why the `request` printouts all happen together at the end, but why do they both print Google, and much more baffling, why does the last one say it's the NYT site, when the log line right before it (from within the same `request` call) has just printed Google? It's like the `request` calls are getting the correct URLs, but the `console.log` calls are lagging, and just print everything at the end with the ending values.

Interestingly, if I reverse the order of the URLs, everything looks correct in the output, I guess because of differences in response times from the sites:

```
node parsecsv.js
Logging from within parse function:
URL: www.google.com

Logging from within request function:
Loading URL: www.google.com

Logging from within parse function:
URL: http://www.nytimes.com/

Logging from within request function:
Loading URL: http://www.nytimes.com/

This is the NYT site!

>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Based on the answer from jfriend00 below, I've changed my code to use a `.forEach` loop instead as follows. This appears to fix the issue.

```
// CSV Parse test
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var text = fs.readFileSync('input.txt','utf8');
var r_isnyt = /New York Times/; 

var data = [];

parse(text, {skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){

    data.forEach( function(row) {
        console.log ('Logging from within parse function:');
        console.log ('URL: '+row[0]+'\n');

        let url = row[0];

        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log ('Logging from within request function:');
            console.log('Loading URL: '+url+'\n');
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                if (r_isnyt.exec(body)){ 
                    console.log('This is the NYT site! ');
                }
                console.log ('');
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand why the request printouts all happen together at the end,
>   but why do they both print Google, and much more baffling, why does
>   the last one say it's the NYT site, when the log line right before it
>   (from within the same request call) has just printed Google? It's like
>   the request calls are getting the correct URLs, but the console.log
>   calls are lagging, and just print everything at the end with the
>   ending values.

You correctly understand that the `for` loop initiates all the `request()` calls and then they finish sometime later in whatever order the responses come back in.

But, your logging statement:

```
console.log('Loading URL: '+url+'\n');
```

refers to a variable in your `for` loop which is shared by all the iterations of your `for` loop.  So, since the `for` loop runs to completion and THEN sometime later all the responses arrive and get processed, your `for` loop will have finished by the time any of the responses get processed and thus the variable `url` will have whatever value it has in it when the `for` loop finishes which will be the value from the last iteration of the `for` loop.

In ES6, you can define the variable with `let` instead of `var` and it will be block scopes so there will be a unique variable `url` for each iteration of the loop.

So, change:

```
var url = data[r][0];
```

to

```
let url = data[r][0];
```

Prior to ES6, a common way to avoid this issue is to use `.forEach()` to iterate since it takes a callback function so all your loop code is in its own scope by nature of how `.forEach()` works and thus each iteration has its own local variables rather than shared local variables.

---

FYI, though `let` solves this issue and is one of the things it was designed for, I think your code would probably be a bit cleaner if you just used `.forEach()` for your iteration since it would replace multiple references to `data[r]` with a single reference to the current array iteration value.

```
parse(text, {skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){

    data.forEach( function(row) {
        console.log ('Logging from within parse function:');
        console.log ('URL: '+row[0]+'\n');

        let url = row[0];

        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log ('Logging from within request function:');
            console.log('Loading URL: '+url+'\n');
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                if (r_isnyt.exec(body)){ 
                    console.log('This is the NYT site! ');
                }
                console.log ('');
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

Comment: Woah, good answer! That appears to fix it. I've spent most of the past few years working in Perl, where I've gotten so used to declaring all variables with `my` that I don't often think about scope any more. After reading your answer, I found this great run-down on var vs let: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable
I'll have a look at the .foreach() option as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've  added an updated version of my code to my answer. It seems to be working. Please let me know if you see anything wrong with how I've fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: @SSilk - The convention here is to NOT add your final working version of the code to your answer.  Questions are supposed to be questions.  Answers are supposed to be answers.  You don't put answers into questions.  You indicate to the community which answer solved your problem by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and you're correct about how it works (including that differences in response times are what's making everything seem good when you switch the order around), but your logging has fallen victim to an unexpected closure: `url` is declared and updated in the scope of the `parse()` callback, and in the case where `www.google.com` is logged both times, it is being updated to its final value by the loop before your `request()` callbacks start executing.